# Python Stop a For-Loop at a special number?

Tags: python, list, selenium, for-loop, web-scraping

I wanna stop my for-loop at a certain point. I know the method `range()` but this doesn´t help me because I am iterating in a list. Either it doesnt Work with `range()` or I just dont know.

Globally I save this Variable.

```
productAmount = 4
```

That is my method. Everything works fine. I must delete some Code hopefully you understand this.

```
def amazonChecker(keyword):

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

titels = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')
for titel in titels:
    counter =+ 1
    if counter < productAmount:
        print(titel.text)

sleep(5)
driver.close
```

Best regards

KaanDev

Comment: Use `break`, whenever you want to get out of any loop!

Comment: But do **not** use `break` here! Just loop over four elements instead: `for titel in titels[:productAmount]:`

Comment: `counter` variable is  useless here, use [array slicing](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/)  instead as @JohanL suggested

Comment: thank you guys. Really interesting Approach @JohanL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`driver.find_elements_by_tag_name()` returns a list of `WebElements`.  You can use list slicing to make a copy of this list containing only the subset of items you specify.

For example... to print the text from only the first 4 `h2` elements:

```
titles = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')
for title in titles[:4]:
    print(title.text)
```